# how to use storage Permission in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I want to create flutter apps for downloading files from internet now I want to Check the storage permissions like the code below but I get the error: The method 'PermissionHandler' isn't defined what should I do?

```
Future<bool> _requestPermissions() async {
    var permission = await PermissionHandler().checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.storage);

    if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.storage]);
      permission = await PermissionHandler().checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.storage);
    }

    return permission == PermissionStatus.granted;
  }
```

note:i have added the following permissions on AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Did you import it correctly?

Comment: yes ,  permission_handler: ^8.1.4+2 at pubspec.yaml                                                      
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart'; at main.dart

Comment: run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` .

Comment: As @YeasinSheikh said, always run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` after remove or add a new package/plugin.

Comment: running flutter clean and flutter pub get but same problem